# JFrame use one component multiple times

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm creating a fixture program. I have a page with the button CREATE on. When the user hits create it adds a new button onto the next page. How could I get it so that when the user hits CREATE it adds a new button and the previous buttons move down by say 50 pixels(eg).

```
createFixtures.setLayout(null);     //Create a new fixture panel components
        createPanelLabel.setBounds(160, 30, 500, 50);
        createPanelLabel.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 50));
        createPanelLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        southBar4.setBounds(0, 730, 500, 1);
        northBar4.setBounds(0, 100, 500, 1);
        backButton2.setBounds(20, 750, 150, 60);
        createButton2.setBounds(320, 750, 150, 60);
        sportLabel.setBounds(30, 150, 500, 40);
        sportLabel.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        sportLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        descriptionLabel.setBounds(30, 300, 500, 40);
        descriptionLabel.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        descriptionLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        dateLabel.setBounds(30, 450, 500, 40);
        dateLabel.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        dateLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        resultLabel.setBounds(30, 600, 500, 40);
        resultLabel.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        resultLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        sportDropDown.setBounds(250, 150, 200, 40);
        descriptionField.setBounds(250, 300, 200, 100);
        descriptionField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        descriptionField.setLineWrap(true);
        descriptionField.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        createFixtures.add(southBar4);
        createFixtures.add(northBar4);
        createFixtures.add(createPanelLabel);
        createFixtures.add(backButton2);
        createFixtures.add(createButton2);
        createFixtures.add(sportLabel);
        createFixtures.add(descriptionLabel);
        createFixtures.add(dateLabel);
        createFixtures.add(resultLabel);
        createFixtures.add(sportDropDown);
        createFixtures.add(descriptionField);

container.add(fixtures, "2");   //Labels each panel with a number allowing me to call the number when switching panels also adds panels to main container
        container.add(loginPanel, "3");
        container.add(createFixtures, "4");
        container.add(editFixtures, "5");
        container.add(adminFixturesFootball, "6");
        container.add(adminFixturesSwimming, "7");
        container.add(adminFixturesTennis, "8");

createButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   //Back button listener, switches back to ADMIN fixtures panel
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(container, "6");
                String descriptionText = descriptionField.getText();
                fixtureDescButton.setText( descriptionText );
                fixtureDescButton2.setText( descriptionText );
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should provide code that demonstrate the problem removing all the noise that is not necessary for better help sooner!..For your problem based on what you wrote(i didn't read code, actually i read but i read setLayout(null) and i stop reading) I think you just have to create new instances of that object.

Comment: You should consider creating a factory method that creates your JPanel. As an aside you appear to be using a null layout and calling setBounds(...) on your components. While this may seem to a newbie the better way to create complex GUI's, it's a fallacy, and more you create Swing GUI's the more you learn to respect and use the layout managers and see that these creatures help immensely in creating flexible, beautiful and if need be, complex GUI's.

Comment: @nachokkHow do you mean? My problem is in this code as JFrame allows you to use a component only once and I would like it add a button each time the user hits the button "CREATE". Sorry, I'll try add some more detail if necessary. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Allows you the same component(instance of a class also called object) shows only once, buy you can have multiple instance of that class

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I'm using the CardLayout, how would I have it use north etc?

Comment: @Nachokk, If i used a for loop that incremented ++ each time would that work?

Comment: In the code you provide you are using `createFixtures.setLayout(null); `

Comment: `"I'm using the CardLayout, how would I have it use north etc?"` -- makes no sense without context. You need to read up on *all* the layout managers and learn to use a combination of them, including nesting JPanels each with its own layout. Avoid use of null layouts like the plague.

Comment: OK I will do so Hovercraft, but are you able to help with the problem at hand?

Answer (score 2):

Again, you should create a factory method that creates your JPanel.

i.e.,

```
public JPanel createPanel(String buttonText, String dataOnPanel) {
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  JButton myButton = new JButton(buttonText);
  myButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
  panel.add(myButton);
  // add jtextarea if need be with the dataOnPanel String,...

  return panel;
}
```

---

**Edit**
You ask

> What difference does this make?

You can't add a single component to the multiple containers, but you can create *similar* components and add them to multiple containers. Using a factory method allows you to do this. For more details on your problem, consider creating and posting a [minimal, compilable, runnable example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

As an aside you appear to be using a null layout and calling setBounds(...) on your components. While this may seem to a newbie the better way to create complex GUI's, it's a fallacy, and more you create Swing GUI's the more you learn to respect and use the layout managers and see that these creatures help immensely in creating flexible, beautiful and if need be, complex GUI's.

---

**Edit 2**
Note: if the component has enough significant unique behavior, then I agree with nachokk, create a class to encapsulate it, and then create instances of this class rather than a simple factory method.

---

**Edit 3**

The key is that while you can't add a component more than once to a container, you can add new components that use the *same model* more than once, and that's almost the same thing. Your component's components can even share the same model, for instance your JButtons can share the same Action, your JTextField the same Document if desired.

---

**Edit 4**
You state:

> A way to increment a button down every time the user hits CREATE. So it adds another button each time, but they move down each instead off spawning on the same position.

Here the layout manager is key. The container holding your JPanels with your buttons will need to use a Layout manager that will accept a new JPanel and place it in the right location. Consider:

- The container that accepts the new JPanel can use a GridLayout(0, 1) -- meaning a grid with one column and variable number of rows.
- Place this GridLayout using JPanel into the BorderLayout.NORTH position of a BorderLayout using JPanel. This will compress your grid panel to its smallest reasonable size so the JPanels don't expand.
- Place the BorderLayout using JPanel into a JScrollPane.
- When you add a new JPanel, add it to the GridLayout using JPanel, and then call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the GridLayout using JPanel so that the new JPanel will be positioned well.
- Again, for more details on your problem, consider creating and posting a [minimal, compilable, runnable example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

**Edit 5**
For example, my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GridButtons extends JPanel {
   private JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

   public GridButtons() {
      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
      topPanel.add(new JButton(new AddRowAction("Add Row")));

      JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      middlePanel.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(middlePanel);
      scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
      scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400)); 

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   private class AddRowAction extends AbstractAction {

      public AddRowAction(String name) {
         super(name);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // my factory method here
         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
         panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
         panel.add(new JTextField(20));
         gridPanel.add(panel);
         gridPanel.revalidate();
         gridPanel.repaint();
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridButtons");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new GridButtons());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: What difference does this make?

Comment: @HarryKitchener: please see edit to answer.

Comment: Thanks, so I will be able to use one component on two different containers as usually it will only appear on one container

Comment: @HarryKitchener: no, as you already know, you can only add one component to one container. Your multiple components will all have to share a similar or same model. Think MVC.

Comment: Thanks, I marked your answer as useful but didn't mark it as an accepted answer as it's not the answer I'm looking for. Once again thanks.

Comment: @HarryKitchener: what are you looking for?

Comment: @HarryKitchener your question is not clear for me at all, i can imagine your question cause what hover answered and that is not good.. i think a factory method as hover say is what you need you are creating new instance of a panel then you can add it to the frame ! You cannot add the same object to another frame and show both..btw +1

Comment: A way to increment a button down every time the user hits CREATE. So it adds another button each time, but they move down each instead off spawning on the same position.

Comment: @HarryKitchener: Please see latest edit.

Comment: Do I have to use a lot of JPanels, just seems a bit inefficient.

Comment: @HarryKitchener: nothing personal, but it's a hell of a lot more efficient than the code you're posting. Please look at my MCVE example posted as edit 5 to my answer. Run it, ask any questions on it.

Comment: It doesn't actually run :l

Comment: @HarryKitchener: hm, it runs fine here. What happens when you try to compile it? to run it?

Comment: IT just prints "Hello World", no GUI

Comment: @HarryKitchener: you're not running the right file. You've got to run the code above, not some other class (which is what you're doing since there is no "hello world" in my code above). At least read the code above if you can't run it to get some ideas of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Wow. My bad :D Sorry to waste your time -.-

Comment: @HarryKitchener: that's not wasting our times and is easily fixed. If you want to use our time more effectively though, you will want to create and post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your questions on this site, similar to the code I've posted above. Your current posted code (which I've again just gone through now) is worthless to us as it does not run and does not allow us to understand your problem at all. Please read the [mcve link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get an idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks for being so kind. I've read over it and will be sure to do it next time.